# How to use Mcrypt constants outside Mcrypt?

Tags: php, constants, mcrypt

How to use Mcrypt constants outside Mcrypt?

I need to call a function like: `$s->encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);` but those constants only works when I call them directly into a Mcrypt function like `mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, '', MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, '')`;.

How can I call those constants?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, those are just strings:

```
MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256: "rijndael-256"
MCRYPT_MODE_CBC: "cbc"
```

Try passing those strings with your function.

Comment: LOL okay thank you Marty, I will never forget that now that I know it hehehe. (Easy reps ;))